# React-admin: how can i fix this view disaster?

Tags: css, view, react-admin

I am a frontend developer and I am working on a web app project using react-admin.

The code is fine, no errors. I launch the app. At first it looks the way it is supposed to look. A few components with tables, menu bar, etc. However, after a few clicks the view goes bunkers. Elements that should be at the top go to the bottom, elements disappear, there are boxes with shadows around elements. The view gets squished, a total disaster!

Can anyone give me any suggestions about what might have caused it and how to fix this issue?

[image: the view disaster]

Comment: Can you add a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit) or some code examples?

Comment: Maarti, thank you for your reply! It is a big project with a couple thousands of lines of code, so I do not know how that would be useful..

Comment: Does this happen with a production build? If yes, it might be related to the following issue. Let me know if it helps. https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1782

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `material-ui` from your dependencies. You have to use just the `material-ui` version that comes from `react-admin(1.4.0)` because the CSS classes from the latest versions of `material-ui(>2.0.0)` clash with the internal `react-admin` components.

Comment: OMG, yes! This is so important. I nearly had a heart attack when I saw my UI in production - it was SO broken.